# Не работает Enter в макросе Vim

Tags: vim, макросы

Записал макрос для редактирования текста в latex: переход в начало строки, на 82 символа вправо, на СЛОВО влево, режим вставки, enter на новую строку, esc выход в нормальный режим.

Вот, что записалось в регистр:

```
:reg k
Type Name Content
  c  "k   082lBi^M^M^[
```

Применяя макрос, вместо желаемого получается такая же команда, но без `Enter`.

Я так понимаю, что `^M` это `Enter`, но почему их тогда 2.

Также я попытался записать макрос через `init.vim`:

```
let @k='082lBi^M^['
```

Но тогда при выполнении макроса, где должен был быть переход на новую строку, печатается `^M^[`, оставаясь в режиме вставки.

Comment: Не ясно почему не работает макрос. Должен работать. Что касается создания макроса через `let`, то вы, очевидно, вводите символы `^` и `M` дословно, т.е. как два символа, а нужно вводить именно как `Enter`, для этого перед вводом `Enter` нажмите `Ctrl`+`v`. То же касается и `Esc`.

Comment: @Roman, Спасибо за помощь! Набрал `ctrl`+`v`, но теперь не могу сообразить, как набирать `Esc`, ведь в vim комбинация клавиш `ctrl`+`[` это выйти из режима вставки.

Comment: Вы пробовали и у вас не работает? Суть `Ctrl`+`v` в том, что следующий символ вставляется как есть и не интерпретируется vim-ом, т.е. произойдет вставка символа и не будет выхода из режима вставки. Так что просто нажимайте одновременно `Ctrl` и `v`, в потом `Esc`.

Comment: @Roman, получилось вставить. Ситуация без изменений( А может какие-нибудь настройки в конфиге мешают?

Comment: У меня идей нет. Я пробовал и у меня подобный макрос работает без проблем. Я бы попробовал более простой (который буквально только Enter вставляет) для отладки запустить и посмотреть.

Comment: @Roman, если у меня все правильно работает, и обычное нажатие `Enter` переводит курсор в начало следующей строки, то макрос с одним `Enter` работает. Также проверил макрос с перемещением и входом в режим вставки - работает. Макрос: режим вставки и `Enter` по-прежнему нет.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить vim без исполнения комманд из vimrc командой `vim -u NONE` и посмотрите есть ли разница. Если работает, значит что-то в vimrc ломает это.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman, попробовал, заработало) Стал искать в `init.vim`, что может мешать и в итоге нашел. Это настройка клавиш сопоставления для `luasnip`. В частности появляется окно автокомплита для выбора нужного варианта, затем нужно нажать `Enter` для подтверждения. Закомментировал следующий код, макрос заработал.

```
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm {
        behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Replace,
        select = true,
    },
```

В остальных сценариях `Enter` ведет себя нормально.
Спасибо за помощь!